# AuthenticationChallenge is called just once

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using NSURLConnection to connect to a server. It uses basic authorization. This is my code:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:[defaults objectForKey:@"SavedUserName"]
                                                                password:[defaults objectForKey:@"SavedPassword"]
                                                             persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

    [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
else {
    [self doAlert:@"Cannot acces server" omg:@"Check your login properties"];
}
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
NSLog(@"11111111111");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
NSLog(@"222222222");
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
NSLog(@"333333333333");
}
- (void)checkIfCanLogin{
[conn cancel];
conn = nil;
//setting request and so on
conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[conn start];
}
```

For first tries is everything ok. - I enter wrong pw, Alert is called. When I enter right password connection is loaded. But when I establish connection, I change password and after that call checkIfCanLogin again, -(void)didRecieveAuth... is not called. That means function returns that server is accessible, but it actually is not.

Any ideas how to improve my code? thanks a lot.

Comment: Unrelated observations: 1. The `initWithRequest:delegate:` starts the connection, so do not call `start`. You're starting the connection twice. 2. The `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` should handle the `challenge` in the `else` clause (e.g. either `performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge` or `cancelAuthenticationChallenge`). 3. `NSURLConnection` is now deprecated and you really should be using `NSURLSession` if targeting iOS 7 and later.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [`CredentialsController.m`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AdvancedURLConnections/Listings/CredentialsController_m.html) in Apple's [AdvancedURLConnections](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AdvancedURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009558-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2), they illustrate how to purge credentials.

```
NSURLCredentialStorage *store = [NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage];
assert(store != nil);

for (NSURLProtectionSpace * protectionSpace in [store allCredentials]) {
    NSDictionary *userToCredentialMap = [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] credentialsForProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];
    assert(userToCredentialMap != nil);
    for (NSString * user in userToCredentialMap) {
        NSURLCredential *credential = [userToCredentialMap objectForKey:user];
        assert(credential != nil);

        [store removeCredential:credential forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];
    }
}
```

The [`Credentials.m`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AdvancedURLConnections/Listings/Credentials_m.html) code sample also shows how to purge credentials from the key chain.